# PHP download freezes everything else

Tags: php, download

I'm running the following code to download a file in the backround instead of just redirecting to the file in the browser, but I can't click on anything else on the page until the whole file is downloaded. Anything I can change in the code to fix that?

When clicking on a link this is loaded in a separate php file, so the user doesn't see where the file is fetched from ($filepath) and it's also protected by a session:

```
header("Cache-control: private");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

if ($download) {
       header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $title . "\"");
       header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
} else {
       header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"" . $title . "\"");
}

// Disable caching
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.

readfile($filepath);
```

Edit // I still haven't been able to figure this out. Now I'm trying with this AJAX code but it still locks the whole page until the file is fully downloaded and it only loads in the background, not to the harddrive.

```
$('.download').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
         url: self.attr('href'),   
         async: true,
         success : function(response)
         {
         }
    })
});
```

Comment: Are you working locally with the built-in dev server? It's single-threaded, so only one request can be active at a time.

Comment: Same thing happens both on my local server and on my Digital Ocean server.

Comment: How about using jquery or javascript ?

Comment: @user10089632 To download the file? I can't process a file in the same way though or am I missing something?

Comment: you want to output the file at the browser? I guess you can

Comment: @user10089632 I want the user to download the file in the background, not in the browser.

Comment: Then use an asynchronous ajax call,

Comment: @user10089632 So keep my php code and fetch it with ajax?

Comment: @user10089632 Any lead to how a call like that could look like? Thanks!

Comment: well it seems that there is more to it than the shown code, please either show me the entire code or explain exactly what are you trying to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151458/discussion-between-user10089632-and-seabass).

Comment: Any more ideas? Thank you guys!

Comment: It's sessions that block. As soon as you have an open session no other page with session on it would be loaded for you.

Comment: @zerkms Aha, but I need to protect the file, otherwise anyone with the link can download it. Any way around it?

Comment: @SeaBass see the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: all below is valid for the default file-based sessions. For other handlers it may not stay true.

It's sessions that block: as soon as one page has the session open no other page for the same session id would be served.

The solution would be to close the session as soon as you're done with it.

So put

```
session_write_close();
```

right before you started serving your file.

It would close the session for the page that serves that file and other pages can be served after that, even though the file is not downloaded fully yet.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: Wow, I think that's it! Amazing! Thank you. I'll test it out a little more, but I'm pretty sure that solved it.